# How to eliminate brackets from caption for subfigures in latex?

Tags: latex, figure

The problem I have is that when I compile the image caption is displayed with brackets "[fig caption]".......................................................................................................................................

```
    \documentclass{elsarticle}
    \usepackage{verbatim}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usepackage{booktabs} % For professional looking tables
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{lscape}
    %\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    %\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{slashbox}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{natbib}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{float}
    %\usepackage{subcaption}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{bigstrut}
    \usepackage{algorithmicx}
    \usepackage{algorithm}
    \usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
    \usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
    \usepackage{cleveref}
    \usepackage{array}
    \newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
    \modulolinenumbers[5]
    \journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}



\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{amsthm}

    \begin{figure}
             \subfigure[]{ \includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{graph1}
                } 
                 \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{graph2}%
                 }
                  \subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{graph3}}%
    \caption{Three simple graphs}
            \label{fig:three graphs}
    \end{figure}
```

Comment: please show the full document including the packages used

Comment: did you try `\caption[Three simple graphs]{Three simple graphs}`

Comment: yes, it is displayed correctly but the brakets after subfigure are displayed too

Comment: I flagged this to be moved over to tex exchange [https://tex.stackexchange.com], hope this helps. I think this is a side effect from one the packages. Try to remove packages to create a minimal sample.

Comment: Did you try to remove the square brackets after `\subfigure`?

Comment: @Marwa Can you please post a short but compilable document instead of this code fragment?

Comment: @Eddymage these square brackets are optional arguments, what OP gets is square brackets in rendered output, that's a different thing

Comment: Dear @yacc, I know what square brackets stand for. My idea was that putting them without any optional arguments triggers a default writing inside the subcaption of each subfigure.

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been addressed at Tex Stack Exchange, see [here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538316/how-to-eliminate-brackets-from-caption-for-subfigures-in-latex)
The proposed solution is to use the `subcaption` package, instead of `subfig`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution here: https://answerbun.com/tex-latex/latex-how-to-remove-round-brackets-in-the-caption-of-subfigures-using-subfloat/

I used the following package:

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}

And the following structure:

\begin{figure}[H]

```
\captionsetup[subfloat]{labelformat=simple}  %% Do not forget this command!
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig1}}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig2}}\hfill \\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{fig3}}
\caption{General caption.} \label{fig:1}
```

\end{figure}

It worked for me!